# Rails sending null parameter in post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a migration to add a new boolean value to my form, but when i send the form the hash value send a null value for my new field. I made the migration like i made the others boolean fiels. Can someone help me in this?

This is the result hash.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gMxerNn+jYk39ADC1EfIio6fqsfdcvtfnlkUOK7WNgmZrIyzRh2VsxBF9E9fAfT0W3oiHX2UYhYJ+MtfnHxtBg==", "campanha"=>{"titulo"=>"Teste App", "data_termino_venda"=>"22/12/2016 14:19", "data_limite_boleto"=>"22/12/2016 14:19", "suporte_versao_app"=>"1.0", "meio_pagamento"=>"iugu", "enviar_voucher"=>"1", "enviar_sms"=>"0", "enviar_push_notification"=>"1", "salvar_endereco"=>"0", "auto_accepts_solicitation"=>"", "nome_moeda"=>"Coins", "pedido_emitido_instrucoes"=>"<ul><li>1</li><li>d</li><li>sas</li><li>ads</li><li>dsa</li><li>sd</li><li>as</li><li>dsa</li><li>das</li><li>a</li></ul><p><br></p>", "titulo_voucher1"=>"juquinha", "descricao_voucher1"=>"<div><b>olea uhaeus hueau usahue a</b></div><div><b>euahush usah&nbsp;</b></div><div><b>euauseuhas</b></div><div><b><br></b></div><div><br></div><div><b>Ut sumo virtute vim, cum vide definitionem eu. Ex agam velit eam, nam antiopam mediocrem an, mei everti iudicabit voluptatibus ea. Audire aliquando ex quo, id has vidit nonumy gloriatur, tollit persius vituperata at vel. Mollis reprimique eu nec. Sea prima labores at, mei magna detracto in, nam deserunt philosophia te. Ex nec decore honestatis omittantur.</b></div>", "titulo_voucher2"=>"juquinha", "descricao_voucher2"=>"<h3 style=\"margin: 15px 0px; padding: 0px; font-weight: 700; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif;\">Seção 1.10.32 de \"de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum\", escrita por Cícero em 45 AC</h3><p style=\"margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;\">\"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?\"</p>"}, "files"=>"", "commit"=>"Salvar", "id"=>"teste-app"}
```

This is my view field.

```
  <div class="form-group">
<%= f.label 'AtivarSolicitação automática de ingresso' %><br>
<%= f.check_box :auto_accepts_solicitation, class: 'input-switch bootstrap-switch-primary' %>
```

Comment: Did you add the new field to the `campanha_params` method in your controller?

Comment: Yes, my params like that.

    def campanha_params
      params.require(:campanha).permit(:titulo, :data_inicio_venda, :data_termino_venda, :data_limite_boleto, 
        :suporte_versao_app, :meio_pagamento, :salvar_endereco, :auto_accepts_solicitation, 
        :enviar_voucher, :enviar_sms, :enviar_push_notification,
        :nome_moeda, :copiar_premios, :is_dup, :campanha_id, :copiar_ingressos, :pedido_emitido_instrucoes,
        :titulo_voucher1, :titulo_voucher2, :descricao_voucher1, :descricao_voucher2)
        .merge(slug: nil)
    end

Answer (score 0):

ENGLISH:
There's must be something wrong with your checkbox input. Try some alternative syntax. If you're using simple_form and your attribute is boolean, only f.input :attribute should do the trick.

PORTUGUESE:
Aqui quem te escreve é um brasileiro!
Provavelmente é algo errado com o checkbox. Você está usando simple form?
Se sim, e o campo for booleano, basta fazer f.input :atributo. Será exibido como checkbox e acredito que o valor será enviado corretamente...

Hope it helps!

Comment: Resolvi o problema mudando o nome da variável, eu realmente não imagino porque esse nome causou esse problema.